# How to convert month from unix timestamp from numbers to name of the month?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, timestamp

I already draw chart from google chart. This is the chart

[image]

This is my sql

```
$sql = 'SELECT ljj.job_id, SUM(CASE WHEN ljj.job_type = "0" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS jobcount, SUM(CASE WHEN ljj.job_type = "1" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS interncount, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished)) AS month FROM {local_jobs_job} ljj INNER JOIN {local_jobs_location} ljl ON ljj.job_location = ljl.location_id INNER JOIN {local_companydetail} lc ON ljj.job_company_userid = lc.userid WHERE lc.link = "1" GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished))';
```

How to convert the month which are in numbers to name like Jan, March, July etc?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using mySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`monthname`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) function instead of `month`:

```
SELECT     ljj.job_id, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN ljj.job_type = "0" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS jobcount, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN ljj.job_type = "1" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS interncount, 
           MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished)) AS "month" -- Here!
FROM       {local_jobs_job} ljj 
INNER JOIN {local_jobs_location} ljl ON ljj.job_location = ljl.location_id
INNER JOIN {local_companydetail} lc ON ljj.job_company_userid = lc.userid
WHERE      lc.link = "1"
GROUP BY   MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished)) -- And here!
```